# Congruence of triangles - concave kite

Tags: geometry

[image]

Consider a concave kite $ABCD$ with $AB = AD$ and $BC = CD$

Want to show that angle $ABC$ = angle $ADC$

Is it sufficient to say that since the triangles have $AC$ in common, they are congruent by $SSS$. Therefore angle $ABC$ = angle $ADC$?

The reason I ask is that I read this article https://sites.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m444a05/notes/03-kite-properties.html#Comments where the author shows the triangles are congruent (same assumptions, second section of the page), but does not use the $SSS$ criterion which is strikingly easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed use the $SSS$ congruity criterion, and it is very probable that it is the easiest way.